# Do Kaname's parents know he isn't really their son?

Tags: vampire-knight

In *Vampire Knight*, Yuki's parents had a son that they named Kaname, but that child was sacrificed by his uncle to resurrect the progenitor of the Kurans who was also named Kaname. This progenitor had to revert to the form of an infant and was taken in by Yuki's parents. At any point did they realize that this wasn't really their son?

Comment: I do believe so because when Redo came for Yuki the night her mother turned her human Juri said that Redo had already taken their son away from them referring to how he sacrificed Kaname to resurrect Lord Kaname.

Answer (score 1):

I think they did. Just like the person said above, Juri said that her son was already taken away from her. Maybe this was referring to something else but I don't think so.

Comment: For this question, I'd like to have the volume number, chapter number, and exact quote of what was said.